# Parallel/Sequential Calling of API in React and Redux and Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

I need to determine whether I need to upload photos(calling upload API) sequentially or parallel.

Sequential means when you upload images(calling upload API), you wait for the first one to be resolved then display the image, before calling on the next upload API.

Parallel means when you upload images, you display whatever images is resolved first. So you can display simultaneously images since multiple response can be resolved here.

I wanted to have a condition whether to be sequential or parallel in just one `uploadPhotos` action.
The condition is to use sequential when it includes same filename like if you upload aa_11-01.jpg then you upload aa_11-02.jpg, else use parallel.

Always remember to only identify if its before the last `-xxx`

For example.

```
aa_11-01.jpg        -      aa_11
aa-11-01.jpg        -      aa-11
aa.jpg              -      aa
aa-12j-14kkk.jpg    -      aa-12j
test-a.jpg          -      test
test-b.jpg          -      test
```

**Parallel**

```
export const uploadPhotos =
  ({ photos, size, controller }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    photos.forEach(async (photo, index) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append(photo?.imageFileName, photo?.imageFile)

      dispatch({ type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_START, size });
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          `${API_URL}/photos/upload`,
          formData,
          {
            onUploadProgress({ loaded, total }) {
              dispatch(setUploadProgress({ id: index, loaded, total }));
            },
            signal: controller.signal,
          }
        );

        dispatch({
          type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCESS,
          payload: response.data,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_FAILURE,
          payload: error,
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

**Sequential**

```
export const uploadPhotos =
      ({ photos, size, controller }) =>
      async (dispatch) => {
        for (const [index, photo] of photos.entries()) {
          const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append(photo?.imageFileName, photo?.imageFile)
    
          dispatch({ type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_START, size });
          try {
            const response = await axios.post(
              `${API_URL}/photos/upload`,
              formData,
              {
                onUploadProgress({ loaded, total }) {
                  dispatch(setUploadProgress({ id: index, loaded, total }));
                },
                signal: controller.signal,
              }
            );
    
            dispatch({
              type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCESS,
              payload: response.data,
            });
          } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
              type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_FAILURE,
              payload: error,
            });
          }
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before making any requests, you could first analyse the filenames and group the array into subarrays, where a subarray has file names that have the pattern "name-sequence.ext" ("sequence" can be anything). Filenames that do not have this sequence part, will just end up as the only entry in a subarray.

Then mix the two loops, with the `forEach` as outer loop, and the `for` as inner loop:

```
export const uploadPhotos = 
  ({ photos, size, controller }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    // Identify the part of the file name that excludes the (optional) sequence number
    const keyedphotos = photos.map(photo => [photo.imageFileName.replace(/-\w+\.\w+$/, ""), photo]);
    // Create a group for each such prefix
    const map = new Map(keyedphotos.map(([key]) => [key, []]));
    // Populate those groups
    for (const [key, photo] of keyedphotos) map.get(key).push(photo)
    // And extract those groups into an array (of subarrays)
    const photoGroups = [...map.values()];
    let index = 0; // Keep the index counter separate

    photoGroups.forEach(async (photos) => { // Iterate the groups that can run in parallel
      for (const photo of photos) { // Iterate the photos that should run sequentially
        const id = index++; // Get the next unique id
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(photo?.imageFileName, photo?.imageFile)

        dispatch({ type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_START, size });
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(
            `${API_URL}/photos/upload`,
            formData,
            {
              onUploadProgress({ loaded, total }) {
                dispatch(setUploadProgress({ id, loaded, total })); // Use id
              },
              signal: controller.signal,
            }
          );

          dispatch({
            type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCESS,
            payload: response.data,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch({
            type: constants.UPLOAD_PHOTOS_FAILURE,
            payload: error,
          });
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thank you looks great! anyway for the regex I think anything before the `-numberOrText.ext` should be looked at only. If its `aaaa_bb-j8.jpg`, just look at `aaaa_bb`. If its just `aaa.jpg`. Just look at `aaa`.

Comment: Yes, that is what the regex does, it *removes* the part that is matched, so that `aaaa_bb` is what remains.

Comment: How about if its `aa-bb-8j.jpg`. Will it just check `aa-bb`?

Comment: No, the implemented logic is that the pattern must be "name-number.ext", in other words, the sequence number should be at the end of the file name and preceded by a hyphen. If the pattern should be different, please specify this in the question.

Comment: Can you edit your answer with it? Should cater both  whether `aa-bb-8j.jpg` or `aa_bb-8j.jpg`. It should just check `aa-bb`? Thank you. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I updated the regex to deal with this.